# Laravel Builder JoinClause::whereIn() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following scope:

```
public function scopeFilteredForUser($query) {
    $query->select('vacancies.*', DB::raw('COUNT(skill_id) as total'))
        ->leftJoin('skillables', function($join) {
            $join->on('skillables.skillable_id', '=', 'vacancies.id')
                ->where('skillable_type', '=', 'App\Vacancy')
                // ->whereIn('skill_id', function($query) {
                //  $query->select('skill_id')
                //      ->from('skillables')
                //      ->where('skillable_id', '=', 82)
                //      ->where('skillable_type', '=', 'App\User');
                //  });
                ->whereIn('skill_id', [2,4,5]);
        })
    ->where('university_id', '=', 2)
    ->whereNotIn('id', function($query) {
        $query->select('vacancy_id')
            ->from('shortlists')
            ->where('user_id', '=', 82);
    })
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->orderBy('total', 'desc');
}
```

And when I comment out the hardcoded array

```
->whereIn('skill_id', [2,4,5]);
```

And try using

```
->whereIn('skill_id', function($query) {
    $query->select('skill_id')
        ->from('skillables')
        ->where('skillable_id', '=', 82)
        ->where('skillable_type', '=', 'App\User');
});
```

I get the following error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereIn() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/vagrant/code/jobs/app/Vacancy.php on line 61

I have no idea why as it seems identical to the manner in which I am using it later in the scope...?

What am I missing?

TIA!

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: Standard Homestead box with PHP 7 and Laravel 5.2

Comment: Try adding `->get()->toArray();` at the end of your function where you're getting the id's.

Comment: Makes zero difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Try doing that query first and getting its results in an array and then passing that array as the second argument. It's easier to follow if it works like that than if you use nameless function (lambda or whatever).

Comment: The query works fine - I have tested that separately

Comment: well then it's the problem in the lambda function. Remove it and do:
`$ids = $query->get()->toArray();`(where $query is the subquery from the lambda function) and then pass the `$ids` as the second argument to `whereIn('skill_id', $ids);`

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do the separate query to get the ids and then just pass them in, and I am doing that for now to stop this holding up work but I would like to know WHY it's not working when by all accounts it should... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
->whereIn('skill_id', function($query) {
  $query->select('skill_id')
    ->from('skillables')
    ->where('skillable_id', '=', 82)
    ->where('skillable_type', '=', 'App\User')
    ->lists('skill_id');
});
```

Comment: Tried that as well I'm afraid - still no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

This code returns a query object right?

```
$query->select('skill_id')
    ->from('skillables')
    ->where('skillable_id', '=', 82)
    ->where('skillable_type', '=', 'App\User');
```

That's why you're getting this error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereIn() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/vagrant/code/jobs/app/Vacancy.php on line 61

The error is telling you: **You're returning a query object not an array!**

You want to return values instead by calling `get()`, `list()` or `first()` then convert it to an array. Try this and see if it works:

```
$query->select('skill_id')
    ->from('skillables')
    ->where('skillable_id', '=', 82)
    ->where('skillable_type', '=', 'App\User')
    ->get()
    ->toArray(); // returns something!
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that with no luck.
Also, as you can see I am doing exactly the same type of subquery later in the scope without any of that additional toArray and it works exactly as expected...

Comment: Yeah sorry just realised all this was in the comments